# Unable to click on search button using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

```
<a href="#" class="button emptyBlack a-margin-left-0 margin-left-xs margin-right-xs margin-top-0 float-left a-float-none b-float-none btnWtbTextSearch">
  <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Search
  </font>
</a>
```

Above is the html code. I am trying to click on that `a` tag.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question and add those code also.

Comment: And also share the link if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's search text which is inside `<a> tag`, you can use `LINK_TEXT` :

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Search").click()
```

or **PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT**

```
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Search").click()
```

or **XPATH**

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Search')]").click()
```

As per **OP**, the below `works` :-

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fldWtbAddress") 
search_box.send_keys('Osijek-Baranja', Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Link_Text tried..dint work though... however..  adding Keys.enter worked  #CODE  search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fldWtbAddress")
search_box.send_keys('Osijek-Baranja', Keys.ENTER)

Comment: oh yes, alternatively you could press enter as well or RETRUN as well to do the search, I wasn't sure your application would do that, so didn't suggest

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any code, I can give you some idea how to solve your problem. I want you to do your own research and solve your problem by yourself.

**Idea :**
You have to first find that element. You can use various `find_element` function to do this. You can visit [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/) for further information about this, here's [official documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). And now you found that element. You can simply use `.click()` function.

Comment: find element was done..and search was working however...search results were not coming... tried ..adding Keys.ENTER  along with search criteria and it worked.. like this   # CODE#   search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fldWtbAddress")
search_box.send_keys('Osijek-Baranja', Keys.ENTER)

Comment: find element was done..and search was working however...search results were not coming... tried ..adding Keys.ENTER  along with search criteria and it worked.. like this   # CODE#   search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fldWtbAddress")
search_box.send_keys('Osijek-Baranja', Keys.ENTER)

Comment: If pressing enter doesn't works then I think you can click on this <a> tag. I think you haven't tried this. If you have tried this and now also it is not working then, I have to look at that website to help you further!